# Linux commands in the vi editor

Tags: command

I am writing a script.

When I select an option it needs to basically run the `ls -l` command.

How would I get that format in the `vi` editor as a line command?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Could you try to rephrase it?

Answer (score 2):

Entering system commands in vim is easy. Just preface it with the `!` character. So for example, if I wanted to run `ls -l` inside of vim, I would execute `!ls -l` in vim.

If you wanted to then capture it into the buffer, you can use the read command. `:read !ls -l`.

Comment: There is a shortcut for capturing it into the buffer: `:.!ls -l`

Comment: or even just `!!ls -l` to replace the current line with the output of `ls -l`

Comment: @user1794469. It's `:r!ls -l` to add the output of `ls -l` under the cursor. `:.!ls -l` or `!!ls -l` would replace the current line with the output of `ls -l`